# Laravel 5.4 login JSON error respond

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I would like to make an AJAX login request, where the authentication fails, the authentication error message should be returned in a JSON object. What is the nicest way to do this?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

**EDIT:**

I generate the auth with the `php artisan make:auth` command.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your choice of what to show as **bold** is a bit arbitrary.

Comment: I tried to "override" the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait

Comment: @apokryfos I jus wanted the highlight the important parts, If you dont like it edit it. ;)

Comment: @LakiGeri: Check this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses)

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 possibilities for the authentication to fail:

1. The request fails validation
2. The credentials are not valid

When the request fails validation the error returned adapts based on what the request expects so if it was JSON it will return the error in the JSON response.

The problem is for the 2nd case, in that case you can simply do:

```
class LoginController {

      use AuthenticatesUsers {
          sendFailedLoginResponse as protected traitSendFailedLoginResponse;
      }

      protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request) {
             if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                 return response()->json([ "errors" =>  Lang::get('auth.failed') ]);
             } else {
                 return $this->traitSendFailedLoginResponse($request);
             }
      }
}
```